# Write humongous number of tiny files

Tags: java, file, io

I've written Java code for writing String into a file. Size of string will be hardly 10KB.

Below is the code I've written to write files. I've written 3 ways to write into a file.

```
void writeMethod(String string, int m)
{
    if (m == 1) 
    {
        FileChannel rwChannel = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw").getChannel();
        ByteBuffer wrBuf = rwChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, string.length() * 1);
        wrBuf.put(string.getBytes());
        rwChannel.close();
    }

    if (m == 2)
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        fileOutputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }

    if (m == 3)
    {
        FileWriter bw  new FileWriter(filePath);
        bw.write(string);
        bw.close( );
    }
}
```

**Ignore errors

I call the above function from 3 threads, one method per thread. I'm not sure which one is the fastest. If not among these ways, which one is good. I've to write 17,000,000 files.

Comment: Have you tried just running your code on a small test set of files (say, 1000)? I suspect the speed of this operation will depend more on the filesystem and less on your method of writing files...

Comment: Yes. Everything seems same. I'm on Windows..

Comment: When using writers, you should specify the encoding. Similarly when you `.getBytes()` on your strings.

Comment: That's about what I'd expect. I think the hard drive, NTFS, etc. are the determining factors in write speed, not your Java code.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy Which language will be best to do. Is it C++.. ??

Comment: I can confirm that file system and disk are the bottleneck. I had to do something similar for a system I once worked on. If you can use solid state drive and it will be MUCH faster.

Comment: @mttdbrd Thanks. I've SSD of 25GB which isn't sufficient in this case. Anyways, there is not other go.. Thank..

Comment: I can't say for sure without actually benchmarking it, but I would be fairly surprised if doing this in another language would make any difference.

Comment: You may need to tune how many threads are writing at once.  What you may find is that writing too many concurrently causes the HDD to jump around.  You may even get better performance just having one thread write the files out end-to-end, as it would minimize the random access time.  C/C++ might give you some slight edge, but as others have mentioned, you are going to be bottle-necked by the hardware.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy I've performed benchmark. Everything writes with similar speed. Thanks everyone..

Comment: Have you tried buffering the output in 2 and 3?  (With `BufferedOutputStream` and `BufferedWriter`.)  I know you are only writing out a 'single' string, but depending on the implementation of these classes (and perhaps the Java version) it might make a difference.

Comment: @Paul I've heard that using BufferOutputStream and BufferedWriter will slower the process for small files

Comment: Possibly.  I would have tried (and measured it) myself, just to see.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try the `java.nio.file` package as one of your methods for test purpose.

Something like:

```
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
Files.write(path, string.getBytes(), null);
```